# How to make font style

Tags: fonts, fontsize, font-encodings, math-fonts

I liked the typeface of this book (scan of paper below) :

[image]

And would like to use it.
I use WhatTheFont app and I think the font name is Hand Scribble Sketch Times Reg.
Does anyone know how I can do this font in LaTeX? Below is my code.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \begin{document}
 \noindent \textbf{2.1 FINITE ESTATE SYSTEMS}\\[2pt]
 The finite automaton is a mathematical model of a system, with discrete inputs and outputs.
 \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: do you have pdf of the original or is that scan of paper?

Comment: basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: is a scan of paper.

Comment: adding `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` is a bit closer

Comment: The first thing you should do is identify all the fonts you need. Use your phone. The app `WhatTheFont` will do the job.

Comment: I think the font name is Hand Scribble Sketch Times Reg

Comment: Since you have known what the font is, all you need to do is to install the font on your machine and use `fontspec` plus `xelatex`.